# Cannot Identify this Font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am recreating a vector version of a logo for a client that was created for him and no longer has access to the original designer, and only has a raster version.

It's a pretty simple logo, but I am having a hard time finding one font in the image, particularly the "Bodi" and "Balance" part. I've tried several of the web based services with no luck. here is the image:

[image]

Comment: This is when you suggest that they let you design a new, better logo.

Answer (score 3):

The font used in "Bodi" and "Balance" look like [Bible Script LET](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letraset/bible-script/script/)

Example:

[image: Example text for Bible Script LET]

Comment: close enough for hand grenades